# Sencha Touch 2 iOS and textarea focusing, automatic scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, html, uiwebview, sencha-touch-2

I have a `<textarea>` inside of an Ext.list in a web application that I'm viewing on iOS in a UIWebView.

When the `<textarea>` is focused and the keyboard is up, if I click anywhere in the UIWebView, then the `<textarea>` blurs and the keyboard moves down. Again, mobile safari does not do this, leading me to believe that this is behavior produced by Sencha Touch, and I would like to get rid of it. I'd like the user to be able to interace with web content while the keyboard is up.

I registered to event listeners - `ontouchstart` on the ext.list, and `onblur`on the `<textarea>`. The fact that, when the `<textarea>` is focused, if I click on ext.list, the ontouchstart fires before the onblur, I am lead to believe that UIWebView is not blurring the field, but something in Sencha Touch definitely seems to be also registering some sort of touch event and blurring it.

Essentially, I'd like to be able to remove whatever events sencha automatically installs to blur things, and handle it all myself. Sometimes I want to blur, sometimes I don't, depending on what is clicked.

So, what can I do?

Comment: "When the is focused" ... when the WHAT is focused?

Comment: Ah, sorry, copy and pasted my explanation from somewhere else, <> were omitted. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate on how you know "Mobile safari does not do the scrolling bit"? On most mobile browsers, when you focus on a text field, the window scrolls the window to position the field at the top of the screen and the keyboard appears below; this is normal behaviour right? And sometimes there's also zooming.

Comment: I take it back, you might be right that it does do that bit, after tested it out on google.com's seearch field a bit. However, the 2nd part, I'm pretty sure, it not a mobile safari thing, as google always me to play with the screen while the keyboard is up.

Comment: So to clarify, you want it so that if you click/tap outside the `<textarea>`, it shouldn't lose focus, but the list should still scroll?

Comment: Yes, let me edit the question quick to reflect on some of these things.